# How to reliably wipe a SSHD (Seagate)?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I understand that [DBAN](http://dban.org/) is great for reliably wiping HDD data but not for SSD, but what about SSHD? My laptop's internal storage drive is "Seagate ST500LM000-SSHD-8GB ATA Device (SATA)". Is there a program like DBAN that is focused on SSHD? I'm hoping to sell my laptop and don't want any of my sensitive files to be recoverable.

Seagate appears to offer the "[DiscWizard](http://www.seagate.com/ca/en/support/downloads/discwizard/)" but I'm not certain if this is the best, most secure option. I'm guessing a simple reformat of my Windows OS isn't very reliable so what is my best bet? I don't want anybody to be able to use software to gain access to my old files, despite reformatting. Perhaps DBAN will work with SSHD since the solid state is just for caching, but I can't find any reading on it.

Please don't suggest I destroy the HD or some other alternative. Thank you

Comment: Are your sensitive files that valuable to a potential buyer that he will try to recover them given they are destroyed by a specialized software, event if it is not a perfect destruction (say, it can be restored using some forensic lab equipment)?

Comment: @EugeneSh. They are sensitive work documents that I'd like to make inaccessible to somebody using software, not necessarily forensic lab (that's intense). My trouble is: I can't find a reliable software to do this wiping/formatting process for me. Suggestions?

Comment: I'm quite sure DBAN will do the job. Although some people claim that it is *theoretically* possible to recover data from a wiped disk (be it HDD, SSD or SSHD) I personally have yet to see proof of anyone or a company actually being able to do that. Data recovery is possible on damaged disks yes but not wiped ones. In my opinion anyone who thinks data can be recovered from any DBAN-ed disk is just being paranoid. But anyone feel free to prove me wrong :-)

Comment: @FakeMoustache, thanks for that. Do you have any references that say DBAN will work with SSHD? I've read that DBAN is not good for SSD drives and won't work well... SSHD includes a SSD, which concerns me. `"The purpose of the SSD in a hybrid drive is to act as a cache for the data stored on the HDD, improving the overall performance by keeping copies of the most frequently used data on the faster SSD."`

Comment: No I do not have any references. But since DBAN will just write random data, the cache will eventually fill up with random data. As far as I can judge the cache (controller) on an SSHD is not smart enough to distinguish between your sensitive data and random data as written by DBAN. As long as you make DBAN also read back the random data it has written then the cache will fill up with random data. Anyone saying that DBAN does not work well with an SSHD will have to deliver some explanation as to why that would be to convince me.

Comment: How do I `"make DBAN also read back the random data it has written"`. Is this a simple checkbox within the software?

Comment: I do not know, I know DBAN exists but never have the need to use it. SInce the payed version meets several wiping standards I am quite sure that it does read back to check that the writing has been done properly. To be 100% sure, I would ask the DBAN people.

Answer (score -1):

REMEMBER - SSHD is different from HDD & SSD

HDD - wipe 10 times means not a big issue.
SSD - wipe 10 times means you are destroying it

SSHD - has SSD that should not be wiped, has HDD Platters that must be wiped, do NOT waste your time trying to find a way to successfully wipe the SSDH and not destroy it, it does NOT happen.

It's best to use SSHD, when it's done and time to buy a new one, put on 7 time wiping, the SSD part of the SSHD will be destroyed, the HDD part of the SSHD will be wiped clean.

At this point it's damaged, just throw it.
but
if you are so concerned then do NOT waste your time on wiping it and just take a set of screwdriver, dismantle the HDD, break any chips into 2 pieces, admire the platters then take the same screw driver and scratch them without leaving an inch gap, toss it into 4 or 5 garbage bins in different areas so less probability of them coming together again.

Moral: DO NOT WASTE TIME TRYING TO WIPE SSHD - It is best to USE and Throw it.

Comment: SSDs aren't as vulnerable as you might think. Overwriting SSDs is typically pointless because the internal controller decides where to actually write, so it's possible you're not writing where you think you do. Also most such drives encrypt the data internally, so all you have to do is reset the encryption key, which typically can be done using software provided by the manufacturer.

Comment: Uhhh... what? Just picking a very cheap, basic example, the 120GB 850 EVO is rated for 75TBW. That's 625 full drive writes. And it only goes up from there. 10 drive writes? 7 drive writes? Those are nothing. There are other reasons attempting to wipe a SSD is ineffective, but that has nothing to do with "destroying" the drive.

Answer (score -1):

If you're absolutely paranoid wipe it with Gutmann method, it overwrites in 35 passes, for whole HDD, it might consume lot of time though

Comment: Why is 35 passes better than 1?

Comment: because traces might still remain in platters or magnetic fields of hardrive